# I am having trouble binding knockout js viewmodel

Tags: c#, jquery, html, json, knockout.js

when it comes to JavaScript I find it difficult to swallow. I have been trying to bind data from my back end to the client but I haven't been successful. I think Its time for someone to show me my mistakes. here are the codes.

```
$(".tab a").click(function (e) {
var url = "";
var data = "";
var Item = "";
var test = $(e.target).text();
if(test === '#') {
    var url = "#";
} 
else if (test === '#') {
    var url = "#";
} else if (test === '#') {
    var url = '#';
} else if (test === '#') {
    url = '#';
}
else {
    throw new Error('hello');
}


function userViewmodel() {

    var self = this;

     
    self.Id = ko.observable("");
    self.Link = ko.observable("");
    self.Image = ko.observable("");
    self.Title = ko.observable("");
    self.Ajax = ko.observable("");




    getUserInfo();

    function getUserInfo() {

             $.getJSON("../../Home/tabcontent?=" + url)
            .done(function (data) {


                self.Id(data.id);
                self.Link(data.link);
                self.Image(data.image);
                self.Title(data.title);
                self.Ajax(data.ajax);


            });
    }

};

ko.applyBindings(new userViewmodel());


});
```

I am trying to bind to this.

```
 <div class="row col s12" style="margin-top:18px;" id="test-swipe-1">

            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {

                <div class="col s12 m6 l3">
                    <div class="card z-depth-4">
                        <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light" style="height:350px">
                            <a href="@Url.Action("Movie", "Home", new {id= @item.id, title= @item.title})">
                                <img class="activat" src="@item.image">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-content blue-grey darken-4">
                            <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-1"><a class="a-title truncate" style="color:inherit">@item.title</a><i class="material-icons right" onclick="loadDoc('@item.id', '@item.ajax')">more_vert</i></span>
                            <p><a href="#" >Report broken link</a></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-reveal blue-grey darken-4">
                            <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-1 title-wrap">@item.title<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
                            <div id="@item.id"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
```

I know its in razor view, I left it like that so you can understand how I want the data to be formatted.
please how do I bind the data to the html tags?

Comment: try once:- `function userViewmodel() {

    var self = this;
 function getUserInfo() {
  $.getJSON("../../Home/tabcontent?=" + url).done(function (data) {
   return data;
  });
    }
 var data = getUserInfo();
    self.Id(data.id);
 self.Link(data.link);
 self.Image(data.image);
 self.Title(data.title);
 self.Ajax(data.ajax);  

};`

Comment: In what ways haven't you been successful? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: @Jason my grid is not populating.

Comment: @Anant please could you take your comment to the answer section?

Comment: @Cody  why? is it working?

Comment: I don't see any knockout bindings being used currently. Are you saying you want the razor code converted to knockout instead?

Comment: @Jason I explained that on my original post. where you have the each loop I can easily put data-bind=

Comment: here is a good place to start, some nice interactive tutorials http://learn.knockoutjs.com/